# Subdomain URL 301 redirect to non-subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, http-status-code-301

I have some subdomain URL's that I would like to 301 redirect to a new non-subdomain URL, could someone give me one example on how to do this so I can apply it to my other URL's.
The .com/url will vary quite a bit

Old URL:

http://products.mysite.com/klim--siteassign-Snowmobile--_n-96

New URL:

http://www.mysite.com/klim.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^products\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-.*$ http://www.mysite.com/$1.html [L,R=301,NC]
```